# Sending mail through bash used to work, no longer working

Tags: bash, scripts, email, postfix, sendmail

4 months ago I made a .sh script to send myself my IP address every some time to be able to connect to my computer remotely with ssh. For a few months I didn't use it cause I worked at home.
I'm about to leave for some time again so I'll be using it to connect to my desktop computer, only, for no reason at all, **I no longer receive the mail when I run the script**, even though the script seems to run as it always has.
I upgraded sendmail-bin and mailutils, which from what I remember (and from reviewing my bash command history from when I made the script) is all what I installed and used back then to make the script.

It's simple, essentially a 5 line script, and it goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "O.K."

while true
do
        ip="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
        echo "My WAN/Public IP address: ${ip}"
        echo $ip | mail -s "${ip}" myemail@gmail.com
        echo "sent"
        sleep 10800
done
```

When I run it the script prints "sent", which I purposely put to confirm in the terminal that it had been sent.

```
me@myMacine:~$ ./ipsender.sh
O.K.
My WAN/Public IP address: 111.111.11.111
sent
```

I even still have the emails with my IP address from back then in my gmail spam folder (I used to get it in my spam folder, which was fine for me, now I don't get the mail at all), the old mail has my own computer's username and name as domain in the sending address as it should. 
I really can't think of anything I'm doing differently, nothing; essentially it's all the same, and thus can't come up with any reason why it wouldn't work. I don't get any email anymore, **that's all I know**. 
I've also tried a hotmail.com address.

I was hoping you guys could help me understand why I'm not getting the email and what I could do to fix it.

Also I already know there are ways to use my own gmail address, using other packages along with my gmail account and password, etc. I would rather keep using the same method and keep things simple, again, there's no reason why I should change it if I know it can work; simplicity is all what my script was about.

Thank you.

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is what I get by running `tail -f /var/log/maillog`:

```
me@myComputer:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9213]: w542YSqo007914: to=<me@myComputer>, delay=05:30:42, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=3000000, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9230]: w542Vs2b007865: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9230]: w542Vs2b007865: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9213]: w542Vs2b007865: to=<me@myComputer>, delay=05:33:16, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=3090000, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9231]: w542JjVF007748: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9231]: w542JjVF007748: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9213]: w542JjVF007748: to=<me@myComputer>, delay=05:45:25, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=3180000, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9232]: w542B0U6007560: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9232]: w542B0U6007560: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:05:10 myComputer sm-mta[9213]: w542B0U6007560: to=<me@myComputer>, delay=05:54:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=3270000, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
```

This is what I get once I run the script (`./ipsender.sh`):

```
Jun  4 03:11:09 myComputer sendmail[9292]: My unqualified host name (myComputer) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

Here is a very long pause, the script will stand by. After the mail command is done and "sent" is printed from the script, I get this on the mail.log:

```
Jun  4 03:12:09 myComputer sendmail[9292]: unable to qualify my own domain name (myComputer) -- using short name
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sendmail[9292]: w548C9EK009292: from=me@myComputer, size=134, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040812.w548C9EK009292@myComputer>, relay=me@localhost
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9303]: w548CAhp009303: from=<me@myComputer>, size=383, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040812.w548C9EK009292@myComputer>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sendmail[9292]: w548C9EK009292: to=<email@gmail.com>, ctladdr=me@myComputer (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30134, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w548CAhp009303 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9305]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9305]: w548CAhp009303: to=<email@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<me@myComputer> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120383, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.198.26], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9305]: w548CAhp009303: w548CAhp009305: DSN: Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9307]: w548CAhp009305: Warning: program /usr/sbin/sensible-mda unsafe: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9307]: w548CAhp009305: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /usr/sbin/sensible-mda: No such file or directory
Jun  4 03:12:10 myComputer sm-mta[9305]: w548CAhp009305: to=<me@myComputer>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
```

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

After installing `sensible-mda`, the output of `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` is the following (still won't receive any email):

```
casillas@DeepNoble:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
Jun  4 03:46:19 DeepNoble sm-mta[11230]: w548kJ5M011230: to=<casillas@DeepNoble>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Jun  4 03:47:14 DeepNoble sendmail[11253]: My unqualified host name (DeepNoble) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sendmail[11253]: unable to qualify my own domain name (DeepNoble) -- using short name
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sendmail[11253]: w548mESn011253: from=casillas@DeepNoble, size=134, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040848.w548mESn011253@DeepNoble>, relay=casillas@localhost
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sm-mta[11277]: w548mECQ011277: from=<casillas@DeepNoble>, size=383, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040848.w548mESn011253@DeepNoble>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sendmail[11253]: w548mESn011253: to=<jose.e.casillas@gmail.com>, ctladdr=casillas@DeepNoble (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30134, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w548mECQ011277 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sm-mta[11279]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sm-mta[11279]: w548mECQ011277: to=<jose.e.casillas@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<casillas@DeepNoble> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120383, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.67.26], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sm-mta[11279]: w548mECQ011277: w548mECQ011279: DSN: Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:48:14 DeepNoble sm-mta[11279]: w548mECQ011279: to=<casillas@DeepNoble>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Runs the script and then:

```
Jun  4 03:52:42 DeepNoble sendmail[11335]: My unqualified host name (DeepNoble) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

Long pause, script prints "sent" and then:

```
Jun  4 03:53:42 DeepNoble sendmail[11335]: unable to qualify my own domain name (DeepNoble) -- using short name
Jun  4 03:53:42 DeepNoble sendmail[11335]: w548rgKs011335: from=casillas@DeepNoble, size=134, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040853.w548rgKs011335@DeepNoble>, relay=casillas@localhost
Jun  4 03:53:42 DeepNoble sm-mta[11342]: w548rgYu011342: from=<casillas@DeepNoble>, size=383, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201806040853.w548rgKs011335@DeepNoble>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun  4 03:53:42 DeepNoble sendmail[11335]: w548rgKs011335: to=<jose.e.casillas@gmail.com>, ctladdr=casillas@DeepNoble (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30134, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w548rgYu011342 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 03:53:42 DeepNoble sm-mta[11344]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Jun  4 03:53:43 DeepNoble sm-mta[11344]: w548rgYu011342: to=<jose.e.casillas@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<casillas@DeepNoble> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120383, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.198.27], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:53:43 DeepNoble sm-mta[11344]: w548rgYu011342: w548rhYu011344: DSN: Service unavailable
Jun  4 03:53:43 DeepNoble sm-mta[11344]: w548rhYu011344: to=<casillas@DeepNoble>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is what I get from reading my local mail (`echo p | mail`), I've blurred my current IP adress with "`+++.+++.++.+++`":

```
me@myComputer:~$ echo p | mail
"/var/mail/me": 23 messages 23 new
>N   1 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2540  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   2 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  64/2674  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   3 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2540  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   4 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2541  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   5 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2541  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   6 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2540  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   7 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2541  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   8 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2542  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N   9 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2540  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  10 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2543  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  11 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2517  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  12 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2518  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  13 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2519  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  14 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2519  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  15 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2518  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  16 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2518  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  17 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  64/2651  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  18 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2519  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  19 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2516  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  20 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:45  68/2519  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  21 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:46  64/2674  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  22 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:48  68/2538  Returned mail: see transcript for details
 N  23 Mail Delivery Subs lun jun  4 03:53  68/2540  Returned mail: see transcript for details
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
    by myComputer (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) id w548GKL8009375;
    Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:20 -0500
Date: Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:20 -0500
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON>
Message-Id: <201806040816.w548GKL8009375@myComputer>
To: <me@myComputer>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="w548GKL8009375.1528100180/myComputer"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)
Content-Length: 1983

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--w548GKL8009375.1528100180/myComputer

The original message was received at Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:19 -0500
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<email@gmail.com>
    (reason: 550-5.7.1 [+++.+++.++.+++] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-5.7.1 [+++.+++.++.+++] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
<<< 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
<<< 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
<<< 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError q52-v6si5112685otc.25 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--w548GKL8009375.1528100180/myComputer
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; myComputer
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:19 -0500

Final-Recipient: RFC822; email@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 [+++.+++.++.+++] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:20 -0500

--w548GKL8009375.1528100180/myComputer
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <me@myComputer>
Received: from myComputer (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by myComputer (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) with ESMTP id w548GJL8009373
    for <email@gmail.com>; Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:19 -0500
Received: (from me@localhost)
    by myComputer (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id w548GJsR009365;
    Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:19 -0500
Date: Mon, 4 Jun 2018 03:16:19 -0500
From: me <me@myComputer>
Message-Id: <201806040816.w548GJsR009365@myComputer>
Subject: regarding the incredibly deadly viper
To: <email@gmail.com>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.99)

--w548GKL8009375.1528100180/myComputer--


Saved 1 message in /home/me/mbox
Held 22 messages in /var/mail/me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<<< 550-5.7.1 [+++.+++.++.+++] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
<<< 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
<<< 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
<<< 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError q52-v6si5112685otc.25 - gsmtp
```

Google no longer allows your IP to send mail to their servers directly. You must use a SMTP relay.

Comment: I may upgrade to a static IP address or learn what an SMTP Relay is to see it's use for my case. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is probably the same problem with Hotmail. Major e-mail providers receive *a lot* of spam, so they have to use drastic anti-spam measures such as rejecting all mail from "unusual" IPs.

Comment: @fkraiem less "unusual IPs" and more "Dynamic ISP ranges, known compromised ranges, etc."  (As an IT Security guy I see many dynamic residential internet ranges blocked, as well as swathes of 'compromised' system IPs blocked as well)